# Use of absolute value sign for determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I was wondering if there is a connection with the use of absolute value signs with the notation of a matrix's determinant.  I understand there is some quantifying characteristic with the determinant of a matrix.  It is easy to see the absolute value as a distance function, in the spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well as $\mathbb{C}^n$.  I was wondering if the determinant can be thought of as a "distance" per se in relation to matrices and if that was the determining factor (pardon the pun) in using the notation.

Comment: The determinant is +1 or -1 times the volume of the (generalized) parallelepiped given by the row vectors of the matrix. In that sense it is a generalization of length, to area, volume, hypervolume, and so on. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Determinants_as_Size_Functions